# Cant open sln file latest version of VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi guys I feel stupid for asking but how do you open a SLN file in VS code , I am a pretty new user and all of the YouTube tutorials are outdated.

I tried asking chat-GTP and also got an Outdated response just like on Youtube, so I resulted coming onto stack overflow for the first time in months

Comment: Vscode does not use solution files

Comment: they do I just checked

Answer (score 0):

I was similarly confused when a professor gave me a .sln file with a project and I couldn't figure out how to open it. This is what helped me:

Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are different applications. To my knowledge you can't open .sln files (or the solution explorer) in *Visual Studio Code* **BUT** this can be done in *Visual Studio*.

Once I downloaded Visual Studio, I was able to open my .sln file and use solution explorer like all the Youtube tutorials were showing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).